# Internal Loadbalancing and Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-vpn

Is it possible to 'hide' Service Fabric application using Internal Load Balancing? I couldn't find any guides to do that?

I want that all public endpoints are only accessible through vpn, including 19000 and 19080.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "hide"? Do you want it to not be discoverable by other services?

Comment: Please check the accepted answer for this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617775/a-service-fabric-cluster-in-azure-that-is-only-accessible-through-a-vpn-gateway